# VB.NET Linq - Replace null with 0

Tags: vb.net, linq

FX_RATE field is null in some cases. I am getting this error though I am using isDBNUll to replace null as 0.

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Decimal'. Please use a nullable type.

```
Dim query =
From tl_ancDT In dtReportData.AsEnumerable
Group Join tl_prcDT In dtPostedFlag.AsEnumerable On tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ENTITY") Equals tl_prcDT.Field(Of String)("ENTITY") And
tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT") Equals tl_prcDT.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT") And
tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("TRANSACTION_BATCH_ID") Equals tl_prcDT.Field(Of String)("TRANSACTION_BATCH_ID")
Into tl_ancDT_tl_prcDT = Group 
From tl_prcDT In tl_ancDT_tl_prcDT.DefaultIfEmpty() 
Select New With {
    Key .ENTITY = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ENTITY"),
    Key .ACCOUNT = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ACCOUNT"),
    Key .STATUS = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("STATUS"),
    Key .ACTIVITY_NUMBER = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ACTIVITY_NUMBER"),
    Key .TRANSACTION_BATCH_ID = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("TRANSACTION_BATCH_ID"),
    Key .ENTERED_CURRENCY = tl_ancDT.Field(Of String)("ENTERED_CURRENCY"),
    Key .OPENING_BALANCE = tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("OPENING_BALANCE"),
    Key .FX_RATE = If(IsDBNull(tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("FX_RATE")),0, tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("FX_RATE")),
    Key .CLOSING_BALANCE = tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("CLOSING_BALANCE"),
    Key .POSTEDFLAG = If(tl_prcDT Is Nothing,String.Empty , tl_prcDT.Field(Of String)("POSTEDFLAG"))
}
```

Ragav.

Comment: You can use null coalescing in vb or compare the value received that COULD be null to dbnull.value. Which of your lines above is failing? I see at least one check for dbnull there already. Is that the one failing? Try using a generic type (of Object) initially and you don't get a dbnull, change it to (of Decimal)

Comment: It is failing when FX_RATE field is null for any row in the database. This is the line that is failing.  "Key .FX_RATE = If(IsDBNull(tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("FX_RATE")),0, tl_ancDT.Field(Of Decimal)("FX_RATE")),". Can you give me syntax for generic one?

Comment: Can you deal with it in the column definition of dtReportData using the Default Value property rather than the Query?

Comment: Your problem is you have a DBNull possible column but are using `Field(Of Decimal)` which fails - the correct type is `Field(Of Decimal?)`

Comment: @Hursey Any examples? dtReportData.Columns.Add("FX_RATE", GetType(System.Decimal) is not working.

Comment: @NetMage Decimal is the correct type.

Comment: `Decimal` is not the correct type. `Decimal` can not have a value of `null`. Does the column have a `not null` on it that disallows null values?

Comment: No. This is the definition of FX_RATE stageDT.Columns.Add("FX_RATE")